# How Can I Set Magento Store Timezone For Different Stores Separately

Tags: php, magento, timezone, e-commerce

I have a store in two different countries. How can I change the store Timezone for these two different stores? Do that require a code change or can be setup from admin? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In Magento Admin Panel Go to

**Configuration** ➞ **Select the Store view** ➞ **Go to General** ➞ **Scroll down to Locale options** ➞ **Select the Zone in the Timezone Field.**

See Image Link for Reference:

[Timezone Settings Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpxGj.png)

Answer (score 0):

I found this issue link https://inchoo.net/magento/guide-through-magentos-timezones/ that talks about "Magento Per Store Timezone Settings". I think that's the way to go. I'll updte the progress here.